# If condition in C# not working properly with Time.time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I wrote a code for an object that instantiates by pressing the space bar. Now, I also wanted it to appear only every ten seconds. So, I wrote this code-

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _laserPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _fireRate=10.0f;

    private float nextFire=0f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position=new Vector3(0,0,0);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (Time.time>nextFire)){
            nextFire=Time.time+_fireRate;
            Instantiate(_laserPrefab,transform.position+new Vector3(0,1f,0),Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

This code is instantiating the object every time space bar is pressed, but it is not giving a gap of 10 seconds, which I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Input.GetKeyDown()` only returns true during the frame where the key is detected as down.
It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again.

I think you can achieve what you want using `Input.GetKey()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot you `Time.time` in this case as you are not holding the key down for the entire time. You would want to use `Time.deltaTime` in this case to calculate the elapsed time since the instantiation of the object.

So, in `Update()` function, keep updating `nextFire` and when the object is instantiated, reset it to 0.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (nextFire > _fireRate)){
        nextFire = 0;
        Instantiate(_laserPrefab,transform.position+new Vector3(0,1f,0),Quaternion.identity);
    }

    nextFire += time.DeltaTime;
}
```

What happens is when the object is instantiated, `nextFire` is reset and increments itself every frame. And once the value reaches 10 seconds (which is equal to `_fireRate`), another object can be instantiated.